# python program to sort by vowel count

Tags: python, sorting

what is wrong with this code?? it is showing an assertion error for last two cases i.e.,["aunt", "engine", "aeiou"] and ["aunt", "ENGINE", "aeiou"]

```
def  vowel(word):
    return len(set("aeiou")&set(word.lower()))

def sort_by_vowel_count(words):
    if(words!=None):
    words.sort(key=vowel,reverse=True)


def single_sort_by_vc_test(input, result):
    sort_by_vowel_count(input)
    assert result == input

def test_sort_by_vowel_count():
    single_sort_by_vc_test(["engine", "ant", "aeiou"], ["aeiou", "engine", "ant"])
    single_sort_by_vc_test(["engine", "ant", "aeroplane", "key", "bcdgcdbcd"], ["aeroplane", "engine", "ant", "key", "bcdgcdbcd"])
    single_sort_by_vc_test([], [])
    single_sort_by_vc_test(None, None)
    single_sort_by_vc_test(["aunt", "engine", "aeiou"], ["aeiou", "engine", "aunt"])
    single_sort_by_vc_test(["aunt", "ENGINE", "aeiou"], ["aeiou", "ENGINE", "aunt"])
test_sort_by_vowel_count()
```

i need to debug this code and i am a beginner in python so please help

Comment: Try sorting input  and result before applying assert

Comment: You have a function called `test_sort_by_vowel_count`. Write a new function `test_vowel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only counts the unique vowels. If a vowel is repeated (like the `'e'` in `'engine'`), you will only count it once. You're failing the tests because `engine` has three vowels, but it's sorting the same as `aunt` which has two (but both are unique). Because `list.sort` is stable, it will always keep items with the same key value in the same order in the output as they were in the input (so `'aunt'` ends up first).

This issue is a consequence of using the length of a `set` for your count. Sets can only contain unique items, so you can never count duplicates that way. I'm not sure there's a similarly concise implementation of the count you need that doesn't have this issue.

Maybe:

```
def vowel(word):
    return sum(1 for c in world.lower() if c in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'})
```

I'm writing out all the characters in the set I'm using here because Python's compiler (at least in 3.6) is able to optimize a set literal like this one to a constant (so it doesn't need to keep remaking the set on each iteration of the generator expression). If you don't want to rely upon such an implementation specific optimization, you might want to move the set out to a separate statement.